# React/Redux Typescript HOC: typeof [a class] is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<never>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have implemented an errorBoundary HOC, but when I attempt to wrap it with connect I get this error:
[image]

I am passing the prop to the HOC but I am not sure what I am missing:

here is my code:

```js
interface State {
  error: unknown;
  info: unknown;
}

interface WithErrorBoundaryProps {
  getNotification(...args: any): void;
}

const withErrorBoundary = <P extends WithErrorBoundaryProps>(
  TargetComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
) => {
  class ErrorBoundary extends React.PureComponent<P, State> {
    public state: State = {
      error: null,
      info: null,
    };

    public componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
      getNotification({ alertType: 'error', message: error.message });
      this.setState({ error, info: errorInfo });
    }

    public render() {
      const { ...props } = this.props;
      if (this.state.error instanceof Error) {
        return <Alert type="error">{this.state.error?.message}</Alert>;
      }
      return <TargetComponent {...(props as P)} />;
    }
  }

  return ErrorBoundary;
};

export const connectedErrorBoundary = connect(null, {
  getNotification: getNotificationAction,
})(withErrorBoundary);
```